# Decreasing value of one float when other go up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Trying to decrease value of float - timeBtwSpan, when value of LevelValue go up.

so at the moment when LevelValue change to 2 I trigger my if statment to decrease TimebtwSpan, and it is happening but value continue to decreasing infinity,

shouldn't this decrease it once ?

as per function when LevelValue == 2 something should happen.. but why it is continue to happening?

```cs
public class SPawnHorizontal : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject enemy1;

    Vector2 whereToSpawn;

    public float timeBtwSpan;

    public float decreaseSpawnTime;
    public float minTime = 0.5f;

    private Vector2 screenBounds;

    void Start()
    {
        screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(
            new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, Camera.main.transform.position.z));

        StartCoroutine(decrease());
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (TimeLevel.levelValue == 2)
        {
            timeBtwSpan -= decreaseSpawnTime;
        }
    }

    private void spawning()
    {
        GameObject a1 = Instantiate(enemy1) as GameObject;
        a1.transform.position = new Vector2(screenBounds.x * -20, 
        Random.Range(-20, 20)); 
    }

    IEnumerator decrease()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBtwSpan);
            spawning();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not very familiar with `unity` and `coroutines` but shouldn't you make your `timeBtwSpan` thread-safe?

Comment: If you had a property for your level, you could have an event that is triggered so onlevel change you subscribe to that will one off decrease the timebtwspan

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian there aren't multiple threads handling these, coroutines in unity always run on the main thread, as part of the update loop (or rather, after it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It continues to decrease because `Update()` fires on every frame. In your case you can use a toggle:

```
var _onetime = false;

public void Update()
{
    if (!_onetime && TimeLevel.levelValue == 2)
    {
        timeBtwSpan -= decreaseSpawnTime;
        _onetime = true;
    }
}
```

**// edit:**
To incorporate multiple level changes, you have to keep track of your previous level value and register a change in value. This would look something like the following (assuming you want to start decreasing at `levelValue >= 2`:

```
var _previousLevel = -1;

public void Update()
{
    // added a minimum levelValue of 2 for the trigger
    if(_previousLevel != TimeLevel.levelValue && TimeLevel.levelValue >= 2)
    {
        timeBtwSpan -= decreaseSpawnTime;
        _previousLevel = TimeLevel.levelValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, how would I add another level to it tho? when it turn 3, 4, 5 etc.

Comment: I edited my original answer, see if that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can just write your decreaseSpawnTime() instead of putting it in update(), and It would work since the function update() is being executed infinitely and your levelvalue will always be 2 unless your game reaches another level.

```
public void decreaseSpawnTime()
{
    if (TimeLevel.levelValue == 2)
    {
        timeBtwSpan -= decreaseSpawnTime;
    }
}

public void update()
{

}
```

Or

The other workaround that I've come up with is this.

```
private boolean decreased;   
public function update()
{
    if(!decreased)
    {
        if (TimeLevel.levelValue == 2)
        {
            timeBtwSpan -= decreaseSpawnTime;
            decreased = 1;  
        }   
    }

}
```